# Accessing Stock Item attribute fields in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Unfortunately, there is very little documentation on how to access and modify attribute fields in Acumatica. Let's suppose that I have an inventory id of InvItemID1. Let's say I have ATTR1 attribute I would like to access for that Inventory ID. How would I access Value ID and description for ATTR1 in InveItemID1? How would I modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes are stored in a different DAC from the InventoryItem (Stock Item) called CSAnswers. It's used for all Attributes, not just the InventoryItem attributes. 
It has 4 columns: CompanyID, RefNoteID, AttributeID, and Value.

In order to modify or access the Value you'll need to join the CSAnswers and InventoryItem DACs. For Generic Inquiries and Reports you only need  InventoryItem.NoteID = CSAnswers.RefNoteID, and 'ATTR1' = CSAnswers.AttributeID. When you're working in SQL or Code use the CompanyID in the join as well.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I've tried this and i get the correct attributes coming back, but when trying to display the InventoryID it doesn't come through